# Asking for user input in bash to set variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to have something which asks the user - "Which environment would you like to load?" - with valid response being either "production" or "development". If an answer is given which doesn't match either it re-asks the question. I want it to set the $production variable so I can run different parts of code later on. This is the closest I could do myself:

```
read -n1 -p "Which environment would you like to load? [production,development]" doit 
case $doit in  
  production) echo $production=1 ;; 
  development) echo $production=0 ;; 
  *) echo ... ;; 
esac
```

It doesn't seem to set the variable when I run it, so I don't know what I am doing wrong. Furthermore how do I make it to re-ask the question when a valid response isn't given?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this is what you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash    
while true; do
  read -p "Which environment would you like to load? [production,development]" ANS
  case $ANS in 
    'production') 
       production=1
       break;;
    'development') 
       production=0  
       break;;
    *) 
       echo "Wrong answer, try again";;
  esac
done
echo "Variable value:$production"
```

You start an infinite loop to ask for user input until it's valid.

If it's not valid it goes to default `*)` and you inform the user that it's wrong and then ask again, continuing in the loop.

When a match is found, you set your *production* variable and go out of the loop (with `break`). Now you code can continue with whatever you need, you got your variable setted up.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is your use of `read -n1` which will accept **only one character** in input.

Use:

```
read -r -p "Which environment would you like to load? [production,development]" doit
```

To set a default value while reading use `-i 'defaultVal'`option:

```
read -r -ei 'production' -p "Which environment would you like to load? [production,development]" doit
```

Comment: I would add that it is wise to always use the -r switch on read as well, because it prevents unexpected behaviour when the user types special characters.